# Is there a suitable loop in R for counting the amount of touchpoints within a journey and place final point-of-sale variable at the last touchpoint?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, while-loop, time-series

I am working with a customer journey dataset that needs to be transformed to time-series data on day level. To give a short overview of the data:

```
PurchaseID    Timestamp               Touchpoint      Purchase
1              2015-08-07 19:16:59     1               1
1              2015-11-03 12:31:35     7               1
1              2015-11-03 12:39:22     3               1
2              2015-11-24 22:29:39     1               0 
2              2016-05-21 08:39:44     1               0
2              2016-06-15 15:48:20     4               0
...
```

Each unique number in PurchaseID is a journey. The problem here is that for each journey that results in a purchase, Purchase has a 1 for each  touchpoint in the journey. I want to change this to only the final touchpoint having a 1, as in being the point of sale, like this:

```
PurchaseID    Timestamp               Touchpoint      Purchase    POS
1              2015-08-07 19:16:59     1               1          0
1              2015-11-03 12:31:35     7               1          0
1              2015-11-03 12:39:22     3               1          1
2              2015-11-24 22:29:39     1               0          0
2              2016-05-21 08:39:44     1               0          0 
2              2016-06-15 15:48:20     4               0          0
...
```

I reasoned that the most easy way would be creating a loop that fills a new variable JourneyLength (which I also can use for analysis later on), which counts the amount of steps in a journey. For example:

```
PurchaseID    Timestamp               Touchpoint      Purchase    JourneyLength
1              2015-08-07 19:16:59     1               1          1
1              2015-11-03 12:31:35     7               1          2
1              2015-11-03 12:39:22     3               1          3

...
```

Using a new loop, the maximum of each unique PurchaseID can be used to fill the POS with a one for every last (and therefore maximum) journey step if there would be a purchase.

What I tried so far did not give the result I wanted:

```r
CJDsub$JLength <- 0 # journey length counter, first set to 0
for (x in 1:length(CJDsub$PurchaseID)) {
  if(unique(x))
    CJDsub$JLength <- CJDsub$JLength+1
  else next
  }
```

Alternatively, with package dplyr did also not result in the wanted outcomes. (This does skip the step-count part)

```r
library(dplyr)
CJDsub %>% group_by(PurchaseID) %>% summarize(
  timestamp <- timestamp,
  purchase_any <- sum(purchase_any)
)
```

Does any have suggestions how to solve this problem and get to the right data structure? Thanks in advance!

Again, this is what I want as outcome:

```
PurchaseID    Timestamp               Touchpoint      Purchase    POS
1              2015-08-07 19:16:59     1               1          0
1              2015-11-03 12:31:35     7               1          0
1              2015-11-03 12:39:22     3               1          1
2              2015-11-24 22:29:39     1               0          0
2              2016-05-21 08:39:44     1               0          0 
2              2016-06-15 15:48:20     4               0          0
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `ave` to calculate the maximum date, then conditionally assign *Pos* with `ifelse`:

```
df <- within(df, {
    MaxDate <- ave(Timestamp, PurchaseID, FUN=max)
    POS <- ifelse(Timestamp == MaxDate & Purchase == 1, 1, 0)

    rm(MaxDate)
})

df
#   PurchaseID           Timestamp Touchpoint Purchase POS
# 1          1 2015-08-07 19:16:59          1        1   0
# 2          1 2015-11-03 12:31:35          7        1   0
# 3          1 2015-11-03 12:39:22          3        1   1
# 4          2 2015-11-24 22:29:39          1        0   0
# 5          2 2016-05-21 08:39:44          1        0   0
# 6          2 2016-06-15 15:48:20          4        0   0
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I do get a similar error as with Jonny Phelps' suggestion: ```‘max’ not meaningful for factors```. Any suggestions?

Comment: Update: used package ```anytime``` and this solved the error! It worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: No need for packages. Simply convert your *Timestamp* to appropriate date/time type from factor: `as.POSIXct(as.character(df$Timestamp))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd approach it with the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
# data, convert to data.table
df <- data.frame(PurchaseId=c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3)),
                 Timestamp=1:6,
                 Touchpoint=c(1,7,3),
                 Purchase=c(rep(1,3), rep(0,3)))
dt <- as.data.table(df)

# create template value
dt[, POS := 0]
# find maximum timestamp and store
dt[, Max.Timestamp := max(Timestamp), by=PurchaseId]
# where timestamp is maximal and purchase has been made, then set to 1
dt[Timestamp == Max.Timestamp & Purchase > 0, POS := 1]

# clean
dt[, Max.Timestamp := NULL]
out.df <- as.data.frame(dt)
out.df
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried your solution with the original timestamp and that did not work, got this error
```> dt[, max.timestamp := max(timestamp), by=PurchaseID]
Error in Summary.factor(347214L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘max’ not meaningful for factors```
Tried afterwards with jjjj-mm-dd notation, that did work but gave the wrong outcome as some touchpoints are on the same day and results in multiple getting a 1 instead of only the last one. What would fix this? ```as.Date``` did not work so far

Comment: Update, solved the problem of time with package ```anytime```. It now works.